# Is the second preposition necessary in "operated on on Jane's knee"?

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

I  came across this construction in which  the same preposition was used twice:

- The doctor operated on on Jane's knee last night.

Is the second preposition necessary here?

Comment: I can think of no explanation for this other than it being a typo.

Comment: The soldiers fought on, and despite the explosions, the doctor operated on.  ...on Jane's knee.

Comment: I was really confused when l saw that construction as one of the examples in a well-known dictionary. But now l'm convinced that it is a typo.

Answer (score 2):

There should not be two prepositions here at all. It may not be easy to find a reference as evidence as it is difficult to list all conceivable incorrect constructions.

It is just about possible to find a similar sentence with two *on*s as you can say

> Jane was operated on on her knee.

But even here some would suggest inserting a comma.

Comment: You are right. Two same prepositions here seems strange and rare. I think it:s a typo.